# MYSQL in server not read "Ç" in query

Tags: mysql, charset

I did make a test with my server aplication (node) in localhost and everything run well, but when I run it online (EC2 - UBUNTU), "Ç" character isn't read (replaced for anothers). This happens when I call a query (I use KNEX.js and MYSQL2).

I check the query directly in MYSQL without node and run well.
In DB the data is right.
I try set "charset" in connection with: utf8, utf8_general_ci, latin_general_ci but not run well

The only difference between the localhost to online server that I can see is the system (Windows in localhost). How to check if it's the problem?

Exemple of the problem:
I desire "ACLIMAÇÃO" (THE SAME WAY IN DB).
I get "ACLIMAÂÂO", some times "ACLIMAÃ\x87Ã\x83O" when I change the "charset" in connection

Comment: Please provide `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to see what is stored in the table.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

1. **Check if MySQL is set to use UTF-8**. You can check this by running
   the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'`;. The relevant
   variables should be set to utf8 or utf8mb4.
2. Similarly, check the
   collation settings using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'`;
   They
   should be compatible with **UTF-8** *(e.g., utf8_general_ci)*

Comment: For "character" is utf8mb4. For "collation_connectio/databse/server" is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. Change something? Is one of these more important?